# Добавить правило/исключение для приложения в Windows Firewall

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, firewall

Установщик ПО запускается от администратора и ставит клиент, который должен запускаться без прав админа. Оба приложения проверяют актуальность VoIP аккаутна, временно оккупируя (`bind();`) порты 5060 или 4569 для исходящих UDP (до ответа сервера), а потом дисконнектятся.
Так вот при первом запуске ОС показывает диалог брандмауэра с запросом на разрешение действий приложений (а он с правами админа естественно). Как можно просто и без лишних манипуляций избавить рядового пользователя от этого "страшного окна"?

**Как из установщика, который уже с админ-правами, добавить правило файрвола и для самого установщиа, и для клиента сразу?**

*PS: установщик самописный, на C++ - к коду полный доступ, естественно*

Comment: Вот же есть  [примеры использования Windows Firewall API на MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366418(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @VTT, делать это через системное API конечно же правильней, но слишком уж много кода они там написали. Консольной командой через `CreateProcess` всё получилось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, раз права админа есть, с помощью внешней команды netsh, через execl, например. Командные строки:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Rule001" dir=in action=allow program="C:\bla-bla-bla\bla-bla.exe" enable=yes
```

Откроем исходящие (кажется так, но можно уточнить в справке) на выход:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Rule002" action=allow program="C:\bla-bla-bla\bla-bla.exe" enable=yes protocol=UDP localport=5060 action=allow dir=OUT
```

Правила можно комбинировать и удалять затем по названиям, ежели есть нужда. Правда, придётся потрудиться, генерируя строчки для execl :) Хотя проще создать VBS-скрипт и запускать уже его.

Comment: Спасибо, первой команды оказалось достаточно

Comment: @Iceman Только учтите, что в первой команде ей можно делать всё : использовать любые порты и т.п.

Comment: Понял. Но ничего страшного, ничего лишнего эти приложения не сделают, а если и сделают, значит так было задумано ))